# Where can I find a chart of the Mishna Yomit (daily Mishna learning)?

Tags: calendar, adult-learning, mishna

Where can I find a chart of the Mishna Yomit (daily Mishna learning) - either online or offline?

Comment: http://www.google.com/#hl=iw&source=hp&biw=1226&bih=803&q=mishna+yomit&oq=mishna+yomit&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1694l4155l0l12l11l0l4l4l0l203l789l3.3.1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=cea538d1a472f0ad

Comment: Thanks, @WAF, I didn't think to search in English. Why don't you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

See here: http://www.mishnahyomit.com/

Answer (score 3):

http://dafyomi.co.il/

Follow links for Other Calendars /לימודים יומיים 
    Mishnah Yomis Schedule

Answer (score 3):

http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=45&seriesid=4

Comment: A helpful Web site, but not the standard _mishna yomis_ calendar AFAICT.

Comment: welcome to Judaism.SE and thank you for throwing your hat in the ring. Consider registering your account on the User page to reap all the benefits of membership, including commenting like this!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.mishnahyomit.com/
They also have a calendar builder, so you can make your own calendar in excel format. if you set the start date to 12-25-2021 then it will line up with the Mishna Yomit cycle. or you can add this to your google calendar. https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0?cid=cTlhMmJmdmg1cjR2dTRscXYzZ2t1dTZsa29AZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ

Comment: Welcome aboard! I'm pretty sure someone already shared this site above - did you want to add this information to their answer?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Tzvi and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 2):

Artscroll have one here: https://artscroll.files.wordpress.com/2021/12/mishnah-yomi-calendar_download.pdf

They also have one just for Zeroim here: https://artscroll.files.wordpress.com/2021/12/mishnah-yomi-calendar_zeraim_download.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In [Kaluach](http://www.kaluach.com/) there is a chart - both in the [online demo](http://www.kaluach.net/month.php) when you double click on a day, and in the [desktop application](http://www.kaluach.com/?page_id=22)