# List of Number of Mishnayos by chapter / masechta

Tags: torah-study, mishna, statistics

I'm looking for a list that enumerates the number of Mishnayos in each perek, as well as totals by masechta. Does anyone here know of such a list (or have the ability to quickly produce one)?

Comment: This [list](http://www.misaskim.org/images/mishnayos.pdf) has the amount of mishnayos in each masechta

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7510/759

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/what-is-the-longest-masechta#comment46944_2677

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A Google spreadsheet with all that information (and more!) is available [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AungNn-I1YDMdFR6R2UwWFl3MlZ1a2IwWXhTNmRQX0E).

A [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfG2b.png) of the more relevant part is clipped below:

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you, fantastic! I added a link to the full-size image. What data set did you use to generate this spreadsheet?

Comment: @Dave The individual numbers I ripped from some website probably 10 years ago and then did a little organizing and summing myself. If you download the file you'll find some statistics about length and whatnot in different sedarim (eg. did you know Kodshim has the shortest average perek size at 6.48 Mishnayot per Perek? Nezikin is the longest at 9.25).

Comment: Believe it or not, I didn't know those facts. It would be great if you could calculate the averages weighted according to difficulty, but that's probably asking too much. :)

Comment: Great job @DoubleAA. I added a [Hebrew version optimized for printing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IT2gbLKK4PEJvCVuK0Sj7BoSGHEOYlpkH5SicbLfR00/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You seem to get different counts from the Mishna Sedura. They total to 4224 mishnayot. The seder counts are: 683, 681, 570, 685, 590, 1015. I wonder why the difference.

Comment: how did you get such a wide screenshot?

Comment: @AlexGordon It was a long time ago but I think I did multiple and pasted them next to each other in paint.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.mishnasdura.org.il/?p=466
This page has links to all the perokim and mishnayot in shass.

Comment: http://www.mishnasdura.org.il/wp-content/uploads/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%93-LOGO.pdf

Comment: http://www.mishnasdura.org.il/wp-content/uploads/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%93-LOGO.pdf  The link is in hebrew but this link will work

Comment: This link has more information than the previous spreadsheet since it also has the sedorim totals. It is also much easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

got this from dafyomireview.com

```
/* berachos */
5,8,6,7,5,8,5,8,5,
/* peah */
6,8,8,11,8,11,8,9,
/* demai */
4,5,6,7,11,12,8,
/* kelayim */
9,11,7,9,8,9,8,6,10,
/* sheviit */
8,10,10,10,9,6,7,11,9,9,
/* terumos */
10,6,9,13,9,6,7,12,7,12,10,
/* maaseros */
8,8,10,6,8,
/* maaser sheni */
7,10,13,12,15,
/* challah */
9,8,10,11,
/* orlah */
9,17,9,
/* bikkurim */
11,11,12,5,
/* shabbat */
11,7,6,2,4,10,4,7,7,6,6,6,7,4,3,8,8,3,6,5,3,6,5,5,
/* eruvin */
10,6,9,11,9,10,11,11,4,15,
/* pesachim */
7,8,8,9,10,6,13,8,11,9,
/* shekalim */
7,5,4,9,6,6,7,8,
/* yoma */
8,7,11,6,7,8,5,9,
/* sukkah */
11,9,15,10,8,
/* beitzah */
10,10,8,7,7,
/* rosh hashana */
9,9,8,9,
/* taanis */
7,10,9,8,
/* megillah */
11,6,6,10,
/* moed katan */
10,5,9,
/* chagigah */
8,7,8,
/* yevamot */
4,10,10,13,6,6,6,6,6,9,7,6,13,9,10,7,
/* ketubot */
10,10,9,12,9,7,10,8,9,6,6,4,11,
/* nedarim */
4,5,11,8,6,10,9,7,10,8,12,
/* nazir */
7,10,7,7,7,11,4,2,5,
/* sotah */
9,6,8,5,5,4,8,7,15,
/* gittin */
6,7,8,9,9,7,9,10,10,
/* kiddushin */
10,10,13,14,
/* baba kamma */
4,6,11,9,7,6,7,7,12,10,
/* baba metziah */
8,11,12,12,11,8,11,9,13,6,
/* baba basra */
6,14,8,9,11,8,4,8,10,8,
/* sanhedrin */
6,5,8,5,5,6,11,7,6,6,6,
/* makkos */
10,8,16,
/* shavuos */
7,5,11,13,5,7,8,6,
/* eduyos */
14,10,12,12,7,3,9,7,
/* avodah zarah */
9,7,10,12,12,
/* avot */
18,16,18,22,23,11,
/* horayot */
5,7,8,
/* zevachim */
4,5,6,6,8,7,6,12,7,8,8,6,8,10,
/* menachos */
4,5,7,5,9,7,6,7,9,9,9,5,11,
/*chullin */
7,10,7,7,5,7,6,6,8,4,2,5,
/* bechoros */
7,9,4,10,6,12,7,10,8,
/* arachin */
4,6,5,4,6,5,5,7,8,
/* temurah */
6,3,5,4,6,5,6,
/* keritot */
7,6,10,3,8,9,
/* meilah */
4,9,8,6,5,6,
/* tamid */
4,5,9,3,6,3,4,
/* middos */
9,6,8,7,4,
/* kinnim */
4,5,6,
/* keilim */
9,8,8,4,11,4,6,11,8,8,9,8,8,8,6,8,17,9,10,7,3,10,5,17,9,9,12,10,8,4,
/* oholos */
8,7,7,3,7,7,6,6,16,7,9,8,6,7,10,5,5,10,
/* negaim */
6,5,8,11,5,8,5,10,3,10,12,7,12,13,
/* parah */
4,5,11,4,9,5,12,11,9,6,9,11,
/* tahoros */
9,8,8,13,9,10,9,9,9,8,
/* mikvaos */
8,10,4,5,6,11,7,5,7,8,
/* niddah */
7,7,7,7,9,14,5,4,11,8,
/* machshirin */
6,11,8,10,11,8,
/* zavim */
6,4,3,7,12,
/* tevul yom */
5,8,6,7,
/* yadaim */
5,4,5,8,
/* utzkin */
6,10,12
```

Answer (score 3):

I ve build the list of the entire mishnaiot with their prakim and number of mishnaiot
We join a group of 36 people in our synagogue, so everybody choose 120 mishnaiot, and are reciting/studying 2 mishnaiot per day, so the group will finish the entire shas mishna in 60 days.
(36 people X 2 mishnaiot per day X 60 days = 4320...the entire shas has 4192 mishnaiot, whcih means that the group can finish the entire shas mishna in less than 60 days...)

I invite you to do the same and built a group like ours at your synagogue
You can downloade my list freely...I will be happy if you kindly inform me the success of the project...
behatzlacha...
        Project Mishnaiot 18    Expected Start Date
        Write your name in front of the Prakim that you will Recite/Study   Expected "Sium Há Shash" Date
        Each person shall choose up to 120 mishnaiot
        Recite a minimum of 2 mishnaiot a day, and we all will finish the entire Shas together in 60 days
Massechet   Berachot    Hebrew Name Email   Country Started at  Completed at
Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   5
2   8
3   6
4   7
5   5
6   8
7   5
8   8
9   5
Total   57

```
Peah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   6
2   8
3   8
4   11
5   8
6   11
7   8
8   9
Total   69

```
Damai
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   4
2   5
3   6
4   7
5   11
6   12
7   8
Total   53

```
Kilaim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   9
2   11
3   7
4   9
5   8
6   9
7   8
8   6
9   10
Total   77

```
Sheviit
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   8
2   10
3   10
4   10
5   9
6   6
7   7
8   11
9   9
10  9
Total   89

```
Terumot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   10
2   6
3   9
4   13
5   9
6   6
7   7
8   12
9   7
10  12
11  10
Total   101

```
Maserot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   8
2   8
3   10
4   6
5   8
Total   40

```
Maser Sheni
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   7
2   10
3   13
4   12
5   15
Total   57

```
Chalah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   9
2   8
3   10
4   11
Total   38

```
Orlah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   9
2   17
3   9
Total   35

```
Bikurim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   11
2   11
3   12
4   5
Total   39

```
Shabbat
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   11
2   7
3   6
4   2
5   4
6   10
7   4
8   7
9   7
10  6
11  6
12  6
13  7
14  4
15  3
16  8
17  8
18  3
19  6
20  5
21  3
22  6
23  5
24  5
Total   139

```
Eruvin
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   10
2   6
3   9
4   11
5   9
6   10
7   11
8   11
9   4
10  15
Total   96

```
Psachim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   7
2   8
3   8
4   9
5   10
6   6
7   13
8   8
9   11
10  9
Total   89

```
Shekalim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   7
2   5
3   4
4   9
5   6
6   6
7   7
8   8
Total   52

```
Yoma
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   8
2   7
3   11
4   6
5   7
6   8
7   5
8   9
Total   61

```
Sukkah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   11
2   9
3   15
4   10
5   8
Total   53

```
Beitzah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   10
2   10
3   8
4   7
5   7
Total   42

```
Rosh HaShanah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   9
2   8
3   9
4   9
Total   35

```
Taanit
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   7
2   10
3   9
4   8
Total   34

```
Megilah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   11
2   6
3   6
4   10
Total   33

```
Moed Kattan
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   10
2   5
3   9
Total   24

```
Chaggigah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   8
2   7
3   8
Total   23

```
Yevamot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   4
2   10
3   10
4   13
5   6
6   6
7   6
8   6
9   6
10  9
11  7
12  6
13  13
14  9
15  10
16  7
Total   128

```
Ketubot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   10
2   10
3   9
4   12
5   9
6   7
7   10
8   8
9   9
10  6
11  6
12  4
13  11
Total   111

```
Nedarim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   4
2   5
3   11
4   8
5   6
6   10
7   9
8   7
9   10
10  8
11  12
Total   90

```
Nazir
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   7
2   10
3   7
4   7
5   7
6   11
7   4
8   2
9   5
Total   60

```
Sotah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   9
2   6
3   8
4   5
5   5
6   4
7   8
8   7
9   15
Total   67

```
Gittin
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   6
2   7
3   8
4   9
5   9
6   7
7   9
8   10
9   10
Total   75

```
Kidushin
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   10
2   10
3   13
4   14
Total   47

```
Bava Kamma
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   4
2   6
3   11
4   9
5   7
6   6
7   7
8   7
9   12
10  10
Total   79

```
Bava Metzia
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   8
2   11
3   12
4   12
5   11
6   8
7   11
8   9
9   13
10  6
Total   101

```
Bava Batra
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   6
2   14
3   8
4   9
5   11
6   8
7   4
8   8
9   10
10  8
Total   86

```
Sanhedrin
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   6
2   5
3   8
4   5
5   5
6   6
7   11
8   7
9   6
10  6
11  6
Total   71

```
Makot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   10
2   8
3   16
Total   34

```
Shevuot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   7
2   5
3   11
4   13
5   5
6   7
7   8
8   6
Total   62

```
Eduyot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   14
2   10
3   12
4   12
5   7
6   3
7   9
8   7
Total   74

```
Avodah Zara
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   9
2   7
3   10
4   12
5   12
Total   50

```
Avot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   18
2   16
3   18
4   22
5   23
6   11
Total   108
    Horyot
Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   5
2   7
3   8
Total   20

```
Zevachim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   4
2   5
3   6
4   6
5   8
6   7
7   6
8   12
9   7
10  8
11  8
12  6
13  8
14  10
Total   101

```
Menachot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   4
2   5
3   7
4   5
5   9
6   7
7   6
8   7
9   9
10  9
11  9
12  5
13  11
Total   93

```
Chullin
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   7
2   10
3   7
4   7
5   5
6   7
7   6
8   6
9   8
10  4
11  2
12  5
Total   74

```
Bechorot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   7
2   9
3   4
4   10
5   6
6   12
7   7
8   10
9   8
Total   73

```
Erchin
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   4
2   6
3   5
4   4
5   6
6   5
7   5
8   7
9   8
Total   50

```
Temurah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   6
2   3
3   5
4   4
5   6
6   5
7   6
Total   35

```
Keritot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   7
2   6
3   10
4   3
5   8
6   9
Total   43

```
Meilah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   4
2   9
3   8
4   6
5   5
6   6
Total   38

```
Tamid
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   4
2   5
3   9
4   3
5   6
6   4
7   3
Total   34

```
Middot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   9
2   6
3   8
4   7
5   4
Total   34

```
Kinnim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   4
2   5
3   6
Total   15

```
Kelim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   9
2   8
3   8
4   4
5   11
6   4
7   6
8   11
9   8
10  8
11  9
12  8
13  8
14  8
15  6
16  8
17  17
18  9
19  10
20  7
21  3
22  10
23  5
24  17
25  9
26  9
27  12
28  10
29  8
30  4
Total   254

```
Ohalot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   8
2   7
3   7
4   3
5   7
6   7
7   6
8   6
9   16
10  7
11  9
12  8
13  6
14  7
15  10
16  5
17  5
18  10
Total   134

```
Negaim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   6
2   5
3   8
4   11
5   5
6   8
7   5
8   10
9   3
10  10
11  12
12  7
13  12
14  13
Total   115

```
Parah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   4
2   5
3   11
4   4
5   9
6   5
7   12
8   11
9   9
10  6
11  9
12  11
Total   96

```
Taharot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   9
2   8
3   8
4   13
5   9
6   10
7   9
8   9
9   9
10  8
Total   92

```
Mikvaot
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   8
2   10
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   11
7   7
8   5
9   7
10  8
Total   71

```
Niddah
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   7
2   7
3   7
4   7
5   9
6   14
7   5
8   4
9   11
10  8
Total   79

```
Machshirin
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   6
2   11
3   8
4   10
5   11
6   8
Total   54

```
Zavim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   6
2   4
3   3
4   7
5   12
Total   32

```
Tevul Yom
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   5
2   8
3   6
4   7
Total   26

```
Yadayim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   5
2   4
3   5
4   8
Total   22

```
Uktzim
```

Perek   Mishnaiot/Perek
1   6
2   10
3   12
Total   28

Answer (score 2):

If you go to [this website](http://www.shaschabura.org/Programs/article.php?docid=45&seriesid=4) and choose the schedule of one mishnah a day for a certain masechta, and count the days in the schedule, you'll have the number of mishnayos in that masechta (choose the option for the number of days and not dates). You can do the same thing for a perek.

Comment: Couldn't he just count the Mishnayot straight out of a book?

Comment: @DoubleAA This way, it takes a few seconds to find out how many mishnayos are in a single masechta. I would have given a link to a single masechta as an example, but the link doesn't change for the chart that comes out at the end. It's easy once you get used to it.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://dafyomireview.com/index.php?seriesid=4) you can design your own review programme.

Answer (score 0):

[This list from Misaskim](http://www.misaskim.org/images/mishnayos.pdf) has the information you are looking for.

Comment: Where does it list the number of mishnayot per perek?