# How many Mishnayot are there?

Tags: number, jewish-books, mishna

How many Mishnaoyot are there?

For counting purposes I am only interested in the counting of the author's.  Meaning if the mishna puts two rules together under one halacha that counts as 1 and not 2.
Also, I am only interested in published sets of the Mishna.  I.e. I am not interested in how either the Talmud Yerushalmi or Talmud bavli breaks up the Mishnayot for this question.

I imagine that if someone has access to the Bar Ilan research tools the answer would be easy to find out.

I am curious to compare this number to other methods of counting halachot.

Comment: Note that there are different schemes for breaking up the _Mishna_ into individual _mishnayos_. But I guess any answer can indicate which scheme it's using.

Comment: This is one of a group of similar questions: [_mitzvos_](http://yodeya.com/q/34253), [_Mishna_](http://yodeya.com/q/34224), [_Y'rushalmi_](http://yodeya.com/q/34254), [_Bavli_](http://yodeya.com/q/34252), [_Mishne Tora_](http://yodeya.com/q/34248), [_Shulchan Aruch_](http://yodeya.com/q/34249), [_Mishna B'rura_](http://yodeya.com/q/34251),  [_Yalkut Yosef_](http://yodeya.com/q/34250)

Comment: Note also that the tally can vary based on whether _Pereq Qinyan Torah_ ( the "sixth" of _Masekhet Avot_) or _Pereq Androginos_ ( The "fourth" of _Masekhet Bikurim_, which came from the _Tosefta_) were included in the count. If there is a tally of chapters mentioned as well, a total of 523 chapters would indicate neither were included, and a total of 525 would indicate both were included.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 4192 Mishnayos. Source: The back of the משניות set that's called משנה סדורה.

See this [online downloadable version](http://www.mishnasdura.org.il/%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94/).

Edit: Per @Yehoshua's comment, the link no longer seems to work, but I can still see the relevant table [on the Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20180410001133/https://www.mishnasdura.org.il/%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94/).

Comment: Note that there are various ways of breaking it up so you might find slightly different numbers.

Comment: What various ways are there?

Comment: Cross referencing this number with the internet, seems to suggest that this is the correct answer.  Related:  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/list-of-number-of-mishnayos-by-chapter-masechta/33805#33805

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore

Comment: @Yehoshua You're right. I found it on the waybackmachine though https://web.archive.org/web/20180410001133/https://www.mishnasdura.org.il/%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%93%D7%A8-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94/

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Perakim, there is a tradition that there are 524 Mishnayot, the same gematria as "Talmud Bavli".  I think the number 4192 may refer to actual statements and not perakim.

Comment: I am not asking for the number of Chapters. I am asking about the number of individual mishnot.  This gematria is odd, since the Talmud Bavli does not cover all of the chapters.

Comment: I have never heard of this tradition. Do you know where it comes from or who records it?