# How many Blatt in each perek of Shas?

Tags: talmud-bavli, statistics

I am working on a chart to split up shas among the members of my shul.

How many Blatt (double-sided pages) are in each chapter of Shas? If you have a spreadsheet with the pertinent information, that would be great!

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/list-of-number-of-mishnayos-by-chapter-masechta

Comment: How do you deal with partial pages?

Comment: http://hadranalach.com/static/hadranalach_com_bavli_chart_english.html

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! From your tags I assume you're asking about _shas Bavli_ not _shas Y'rushalmi_ (which, anyway, is usually measured in _halachos_ not _dapim_). Is that right? If so, you may wish to specify it in the question instead of hoping answerers will read the tags.

Comment: @rainrunner if you wind up making a new solution please post it here

Answer (score 2):

you cannot split it by both chapters and daf. it's either one or the other since dafim overlap in chapters. closest thing I know of is this though there is some overlap as before  http://hadranalach.com/index.php?action=t_view&id=16#tabs

here is a word doc version http://hadranalach.com/static/shas_lefi_daf.docx

Comment: I understood the question to be that the person wants to divvy up Shas for a group and people would sign up for chapters, but want the portions to be equalish (or at least know what they are signing up for).  HaIsha Nikneit (Kiddushin Ch 1) and Tefillat HaShachar (Berakhot 4) are each 1 chapter, but they aren't remotely the same thing you are signing up for since one has 40 blatt and one has four.  Knowing how many pages helps create even portions, or at least portions of a known size.