# Listing of amount of Blatt per perek of Shas

Tags: talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, statistics

Where can I get a listing of how many blatt / pages are in each chapter of gemarah talmud bavli?

I found a post with a spreadsheet that has the amount of mishnayos per perek and I am looking for the same concept but for gemara.
[List of Number of Mishnayos by chapter / masechta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18892/list-of-number-of-mishnayos-by-chapter-masechta)

I also found a listing of how many daf per masechta
[What is the longest masechta?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/what-is-the-longest-masechta)

But I don't see anywhere a list of dafim per perek in gemara
Thanks

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37426/27180

Comment: I see he didn't get an answer either. But it was almost 10 years ago so maybe there is something available now

Comment: ok, I found a spreadsheet with the info, but not in a usable format. Anyone know how to easily manipulate this to a proper spreadsheet format? [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z1oRHEGJ0xMWdKHRJG2haJ4TQ_hr9YijaJ-F2aR2x30/edit#gid=0)

Comment: @Devpaq what do you mean "usable"? Might only take 10-15 minutes to just add them all up with a hand calculator and pen and paper. If it helps, sefaria lists gemaras by daf, can just go through those and count that way too, should be quicker

Comment: I am going to manually put it together. I will post it here once I am done

Comment: In case this will benefit anyone else, here is a sheet I put together for gemarah as well as other info I found online for Mishnah and tehillim
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w4D1iUnwtSHCIm66akFGmKdLRGHISRRHrxSCyCEVOb4/edit?usp=sharing)