# Why are tractates arranged in descending order of size?

Tags: mishna

The tractates of the Mishna are in approximately descending order. That is, in each Order, the longest tractates come first and the shortest ones are last (although there are a few exceptions).

In some cases, like Moed, this order makes sense, since there is a natural progression from Shabbat (most common) to the Biblical holidays in order of their occurrence, to the Rabbinical days. However, in other cases such as Nashim, having the tractates ordered by size creates an unusual sequence. Nashim starts with an unusual case, followed by the responsibilities of marriage, then laws tangentially related, another unusual case, divorce, and finally marriage (which ought to come first, as it does in the Rambam and Shulchan Aruch).

So why is having the tractates in descending order so important?

Comment: Not everyone has that order. See printed Yerushalmis for instance.

Comment: I don't think that the descending page volume was intentionalm an dthat was the reason for the ordering. Ramba"m (don't recall where) does explain the reason for the placement of the tractates as well as many of their names.

Comment: Probably for the same reason that Midrashim have a bunch on the beginning of the parsha and much less later, Gemara's generally have a bunch on the first Mishna, and less later on. The beginning is where concepts get introduced, whereas later on they rely on what was said earlier. Not perfectly so, though (I am proposing a heuristic, not an algorithm).

Comment: I heard\read that it's because of the way it was copied by scribes.  They started with the longest ones first, since that would take up the most space on the scroll, and worked down in descending order, so that they could fit the smaller ones in the space that was left.

Comment: Another book that is written with the chapters ordered from longer to shorter is the *Quran.*  ( [According to them](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/838/how-was-the-order-of-the-quran-decided), the order was decided by God.)

Comment: Why can this descending order not be coincidental? You'll find that many gemarot begin by asking about the relevance of the tractate in question to the previous tractate, and nowhere is the answer given that we try to put the longer tractates first.

Comment: @Yehuda - can you give me an example of this? I'm not familiar with the gemara *ever* doing that...

Comment: @ShimonbM see first sugya in sotah

Comment: According to [Double AA's spreadsheet](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18896), there's (looking at number of _mishnayos_ per _maseches_ against position of the _maseches_ in the _seder_, examining each _seder_ separately) a descent in size for four _s'darim_ ([R²](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)>.77 for each) but not for _Z'raim_ or _N'zikin_ (R²<.25 for each).

Comment: [related](/a/116654/170)