# How many chapters of mishna are there?

Tags: mishna, statistics

I was wondering how many chapters of mishna there are. How many perakim and mishnayot in each seder?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Mikie, and thanks for bringing us your question.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Mishna Sedura](http://www.mishnasdura.org.il/), the breakup is as follows:

- Zeraim: 75 prakim with a total of 683 mishnayot
- Moed: 88 prakim with a total of 681 mishnayot
- Nashim: 71 prakim with a total of 570 mishnayot
- N'zikin: 74 prakim with a total of 685 mishnayot
- Kodshim: 91 prakim with a total of 590 mishnayot
- Taharot: 126 prakim with a total of 1015 mishnayot

Grand total: 525 prakim with a total of 4224 mishnayot.

Comment: Acc. to http://www.mishnasdura.org.il/ there are 4191 in total. And acc. to  the spreadsheet lineked in https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18896/18968 there are 4192 mishnayot in total.